# move scrollbar to a specific row by seacrh fields in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a filter in my slickgrid which works fine. Instead of filtering I want to move scrollbar of the slick grid to specific row when I type in search fields and if it matches to anything in my list.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SlickGrid API has a public method called [scrollRowIntoView(row, doPaging)](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#scrollRowIntoView).

Where paraters are:

> row - A row index.
>
> doPaging - A boolean. If false, the grid will scroll so the indicated
>   row is at the top of the view. If true, the grid will scroll so the
>   indicated row is at the bottom of the view. Defaults to false.

So by issuing:

```
grid.scrollRowIntoView(200, true);
```

Will scroll the given row number into the viewport of your grid.

Answer (score 0):

working code in case you are looking for the same thing.

```
function filter(item) {
if (item.LastName == columnFilters.LastName) {
    grid.scrollRowIntoView(item.id, true);
}
return true;
}

dataView.setFilter(filter);
```